# Spring Boot TestNG with Multiple AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, testng

Spring Boot TestNG with Multiple AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests classes initializes Spring Boot Context per Test Classes.

I have defined multiple TestNG Test Classes like this :-

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext
public class TestNGClass1 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @LocalServerPort
    public int port;
    .......
}
```

---

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext
public class TestNGClass2 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @LocalServerPort
    public int port;
    .......
}
```

---

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext
public class TestNGClass3 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @LocalServerPort
    public int port;
    .......
}
```

Is there a way out to reuse Spring Context across all those classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @DirtiesContext Test annotation which indicates that the
>   ApplicationContext associated with a test is dirty and should
>   therefore be closed and removed from the context cache.

1. Use testng suites
2. Remove `@DirtiesContext` and use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and @SpringBootTest`

Check this https://github.com/ielatif/stackoverflow/tree/master/spring-boot-testng-sample

Comment: How can i achieve this using @BeforeSuite. Can you give me a sample code snippet.

Comment: I give it a try using testng suites and without @BeforeSuite check the link in my answer

Comment: @IssamELATIF i am trying to convert existing app to springboot app.if i use RunWith annotation then i am getting port already used issue ..otherwise looks like each testclass is loading its own context although all classes are inherited from same base class

Comment: i aam trying to run integration test using testng

Comment: @Vish can you post your question with code and issue then provide me the link as comment in this post.

Comment: @IssamELATIF link for question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439543/running-testng-integration-test-with-spring-boot