# error while running integration test with spring boot and testng

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, testng, integration-testing

We are trying to run integration test using testng and springboot.app is running fine and we are able run standalone test using eclipse.but when we run testcase using maven command line.i am getting following exception

```
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
SEVERE: Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
```

if we try to load context.xml for running testcase then each testcase is trying to load its own context and testcase are failing with host not found exception.

base testcase class

```
//@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:objectModelContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class BaseITCase extends com.test.common.BaseITCase {

    protected static final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" +  port + "/test/api/";

    protected String getAdminToken(String username, String password, String deviceId) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>om.test</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>springboot</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.test.App</start-class>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.65</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections-maven</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.9-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- only dependency needed -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.plist</groupId>
        <artifactId>dd-plist</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <!-- corresponds to r108 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <maxAttempts>600</maxAttempts>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Update**

Tests are run using `mvn clean install`

i am trying to look for example for same but i am not finding any solution.

Comment: Is all IT tests extends BaseITCase?

Comment: Yes all test extend baseit

Comment: Spring boot is trying to start tests on port 8080 even if you specify `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` . How do you run test with maven?

Comment: Using maven clean install command

Comment: You are using maven-failsafe-plugin and verify goal. So to run integration tests you sould run `mvn clean verify`.

Comment: Even install command execute tests as verify is preceding step during maven build.so this should not problem I feel

Comment: There is another application bound to port 8080. See answers to this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like configuration is correct and server is runnig proplerly on port 8008.my app was not picking correct port while running test cases giving connection refused error

following changes were done in basetest case since SpringRunner is not required with testng

```
 @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:objectModelContext.xml"})
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class BaseITCase extends com.test.common.BaseITCase {

    protected static final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" +  port + "/test/api/";

    protected String getAdminToken(String username, String password, String deviceId) throws Exception {
    }
}
```